# Does Laravel Sync Delete and Re-Create?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm looking for some more information on how Laravel Sync Actually works. I have a Relationship Table that contains the following

`group_id, user_id, permission, created_at, updated_at`

I'm generating an array to pass to the sync command like so.

`$groups_array[$group_id] = ['permission' => 0];`

When I do this and then call sync it is setting the created_at and updated_at dates on existing relationships to NULL. The desired affect would be to have it just update the permission value to 0 on the existing relationship and not set the created_at and updated_at values to NULL.

It seems as if Sync is deleting everything and just re-creating the relationships based on the array sent. Is there not a way to tell this to update existing relationships vs. deleting and re-creating them?

Comment: Can you provide some more code? I've tried what you mention and it does not overwrite the `created_at` nor the `updated_at` timestamp. Are you sure they were set initially? Because Laravel does not set the timestamps for the pivot rows by default.

Comment: Looking down belongs to many relationship, it will try to update your pivots, so either it is a bug in the sync call or misuse of relationships. The question is a little sparse with code, so please include some more :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Many to Many relationships in `Laravel` does not include timestamps, you need to define it on the relationship.

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withTimestamps();
}
```

Comment: I'm not certain this solves your problem, but is atleast a try worth :)

Comment: This was not the exact solution to the problem I was having. The issue itself was more related to the way that Backpack Laravel handles Many-Many relationships, but this was as close to an answer without completely altering the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Post Model
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category')->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag')->withTimestamps();
    }
// Tag Model
 public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post')->withTimestamps();
    }
// Category Model
 public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post')->withTimestamps();
    }
// Post Controller Update
public function update(Request $request, Post $post)
    {
         $this->validate($request,[
            'title' =>'required',
            'categories' => 'required',
            'tags' => 'required'
        ]);




        $post->user_id = Auth::id();
        $post->title = $request->title;
        $post->slug = str_slug($request->title);
        $post->save();
        $post->categories()->sync($request->categories);
        $post->tags()->sync($request->tags);
        Toastr::success('Post Successfully Updated:)','Success');
        return redirect()->route('admin.post.index');
    }

// Delete
public function destroy(Post $post)
    {

        $post->categories()->detach();
        $post->tags()->detach();
        $post->delete();
        Toastr::success('Post Successfully Deleted :)','Success');
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```